# i'm trying to extract the feature, but when i run the script get this error (Error using LBPFeature Too many output arguments)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

```
%% Extract and display Local binary pattern Features for single face 

person = 5;

[Featureex, visualization]= LBPFeature(read(training(person),1));

figure;

subplot(2,1,1);imshow(read(training(person),1));title('Input Face');

subplot(2,1,2);plot(visualization);title('LBP Feature');
```

This is the function for extracting the features:

```
function [LBP]= LBPFeature(I2)


I3=I2;

m=size(I2,1);

n=size(I2,2);

for i=2:m-1

    for j=2:n-1

        c=I2(i,j);

        I3(i-1,j-1)=I2(i-1,j-1)>c;

        I3(i-1,j)=I2(i-1,j)>c;

        I3(i-1,j+1)=I2(i-1,j+1)>c; 

        I3(i,j+1)=I2(i,j+1)>c;

        I3(i+1,j+1)=I2(i+1,j+1)>c; 

        I3(i+1,j)=I2(i+1,j)>c; 

        I3(i+1,j-1)=I2(i+1,j-1)>c; 

        I3(i,j-1)=I2(i,j-1)>c;

        LBP (i,j) =I3(i-1,j-1)*2^7+I3(i-1,j)*2^6+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^5+ ...

            I3(i,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^3+I3(i+1,j)*2^2+ ...

            I3(i+1,j-1)*2^1+I3(i,j-1)*2^0;
    end
end
```

Comment: Well, it looks like `LBPFeature` only takes one input and produces one output. You're calling it with two inputs and requesting two outputs.

Comment: please how can i correct to accept and return two input and output

Comment: You add the correct inputs and outputs to the function definition. See https://www.mathworks.com/videos/managing-code-in-matlab-functions-of-multiple-inputs-and-outputs-97211.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html. I can't tell you what those extra inputs and outputs should be because I don't know what you're trying to do.